# Extrema of the product of $n$ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdots x_n\\ \text{subject to} & (1-x_1) \cdot (1-x_2) \cdots (1-x_n) = a\\ & x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 0\\ & -1 \leq x_i \leq 1\end{array}$$

Without $-1 \leq x_i \leq 1$ one might use the method of Lagrange multipliers, but with it I have no idea what to do. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can still handle this with Lagrange multipliers. For instance you can solve the problem not taking into account condition 3) and then look at the end which of the solutions satisfy 3). Or you could introduce auxiliary variables that turn the inequalities into equalities. $$x_i \leq 1$$ is the same as saying that $$x_i+s = 1$$ for some positive $s$. Note that this just shifts the inequality on $s$ though.

Comment: You should try some test cases with small $n$, say $n=3$ or $n=4$, and particular values of $a$, say $a=1$, to get a feel for the issues.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Like some particular values of $a$, for example, $a=0$, or some particular values of $n$, for example, $n=2$ and $n=3$? The problem is very symmetric in all variables.

Comment: It's easy to prove that the constant $a$ must be in the interval $[0,1]$, hence for test cases, I would use $a=1/2$.